# What's a punchline?

Tags: writing

What's a punchline in a paragraph? Is it the same as topic sentence, or is it a conclusion sentence?

Can you provide a concrete example of punchline?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punch_line

Answer (score 1):

It usually applies to a joke. It's the final few words and, if it's funny enough, prompts laughter.